# Push Notifications after 2-3 days?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an application which requires push notification.
I have provided Push Notification feature but I need to know what if a user has turned off his/her iDevice for 2-3 days or for whatever reason, the device is turned off for few hours/days/minutes etc.

If I send a push notification at that point of time, would the user receive the notification when he turns on his device.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or computer within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one.

Here's why. The device or computer acknowledges receipt of each notification. Until the push service receives that acknowledgment, it can only assume that the device or computer has gone off-line for some reason and stores the notification in the quality of service (QoS) queue for future redelivery. The round-trip network latency here is of course a major factor.

All of this points out that the intent is that a notification indicates to an app that something of interest has changed on the provider, and the app should check in with the provider to get the details. Notifications should not contain data which isn't also available elsewhere, and they should also not be stateful.

Any push notification that isn't delivered immediately was queued for future redelivery because your device was not connected to the service. "Immediately" of course needs to take latency for your connection into account. Outlying cases would be beyond 60 seconds as APNs will time out at that point.

Still you have any query then you can refer the below link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html